# Redshift unload to S3 is extremely slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I'm using a ds2.xlarge Redshift cluster in US West with about 1TB of data. I'm trying to UNLOAD a 50GB table to an S3 bucket in the same region as follows:

```
UNLOAD ('select * from table_name') TO 's3://bucket/folder_name/'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=foo;aws_secret_access_key=bar'
MANIFEST;
```

This query takes about 1 hour to run. This seems surprising since the Amazon website says that we'll have an I/O of 0.5GB/s for our cluster, which means the 50GB table should take less than 2 minutes to be uploaded to S3, not an hour. (20-30x times slower than advertised)

Has anyone else run into this issue and/or found a fix / workaround? If we decide to use Redshift, we will need to move about 200GB of data from Redshift to S3 every day.

Comment: Do you have just a single node in the cluster? How many rows and columns are in the table? If you do a smaller quantity (eg `select * from table_name limit 10000`) does it finish faster? Just out of interest, where is the mention of 0.5GB/s for the cluster?

Comment: The I/O is mentioned here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-redshift-now-faster-and-more-cost-effective-than-ever/

I believe the table has about 80M rows and 10-20 columns. It is a lot faster with the limit

Comment: I suspect that the I/O column is the speed that the database can access the disk storage, not necessarily the speed of exporting to Amazon S3. The fact the export finishes faster with fewer rows indicates that it is related to the volume of data. You could try using Workload Management (WLM) to grant slots (and therefore more memory) to the process. See: [`wlm_query_slot_count`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_wlm_query_slot_count.html)

Comment: One more option to speed up the unload is to compress the data (gzip / bzip2). A lot of time is spent on moving the bits especially if the bucket is NOT in the same region as Redshift. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html

Comment: Adding `PARELLEL TRUE` should help your performance as it will write to multiple files according on the number of slices in the cluster. By default, Redshift does not use this option.

Comment: Can you please check the S3 bucket region ? I suspect you are going cross-region.

Comment: @fez, maybe that was once true, but it is no longer the case.


>By default, UNLOAD writes data in parallel to multiple files, according to the number of slices in the cluster. The default option is ON or TRUE.


https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html

Answer (score 1):

It's very expensive for Redshift to "re-materialize" complete rows. That's why the S3 unload is much slower than the total disk I/O.

The data is stored on disk in a manner that's optimised for retrieving a single column. Recreating the full rows generates (effectively) random I/O access. Your unload would be *much* faster on an SSD based node type.

If you want to verify this you can write all of the columns (delimited) into a table with 1 `VARCHAR(MAX)` column - which will be quite slow. And then unload that table - which will be much faster.